# A group product

Tags: group-theory, terminology, group-actions

If $G$ and $H$ are two groups, and
$\triangleright$ and $\triangleleft$ are a left action and a right action
of $H$ on $G$ by group automorphisms such that
$$h\triangleright(g\triangleleft h')=(h\triangleright g)\triangleleft h',$$
then we can construct a group $G\bowtie H$ with underlying set $G\times H$
and multiplication such that $$(g,h)\cdot(g',h')=((g\triangleleft
h')(h\triangleright g'),hh').$$
This group can also be described as a semidirect product but …

> does this particular construction have a name and/or appears in the literature?

Comment: Perhaps it is related to the [Zappa-Szep product of subgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zappa–Szép_product).

Comment: It is isomorphic to a semidirect product of $G$ and $H$, with an action of $H$ on $G$ that mixes both $\triangleleft$ and $\triangleright$, but that rather obscures the fact that one starts with two actions, so I was wondering if this particular *phrasing* of the construction isused somewhere.